# Why doesn't the Potential Difference reading start from zero

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, rectifier, simulink

While I was running a simulation of a center tapped transformer with and without a filter on Matlab I noticed something strange. The potential difference across the load doesn't start from zero and I don't understand why. One other thing I noticed was as the resistance of the load got smaller the start point of the potential difference got closer and closer to zero. Can someone please explain?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most simulators require you to define the GND point. I don't see one in your schematic.

Comment: @Transistor I just updated the schematic but still no difference

Comment: You’re really measuring the voltage across a zero-ohm resistor?

Comment: @Frog the capacitor blocked the 1000Ω text I'll correct that now. Thanks

Comment: It’s nonzero phase angle at all simulation points… try subtracting 0.05 deg from both generators’ phase angles, so that the phase difference is centered around zero. That should help the simulator show you what you’re trying to see.